# REFESH MATERIALIZED VIEW a través de TRIGGER SIN SER SUPER

Tags: postgresql, plsql, postgresql-9.3

Me surge un problema al tener que refrescar una lista Materializada. Esta vista materializada, sufre algún cambio, y necesito que se refresque.

He creado un trigger que hace un `REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW` al insertar/actualizar datos que afectan a esa vista Materializada, pero solo se lanza con usuario postgres o super.

Cuando es cualquier otro usuario de la BD que inserte/actualiza datos que afectan luego a esa vista materializada, sale el mensaje por consola :

```
ERROR:  debe ser dueño de la relación "VISTA_MATERIALIZADA"
CONTEXTO:  sentencia SQL: «refresh materialized view "VISTA_MATERIALIZADA"»
función PL/pgSQL pro.refresh_mat_view() en la línea 3 en sentencia SQL
```

He probado a PONER:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ON "VISTA_MATERIALIZADA"(id); para intentar hacer el refresh concurreny


GRANT ALL ON "VISTA_MATERIALIZADA" TO public; NO HACE CASO.
```

Sin éxito ninguno.

Aqui me devuelve los permisos de esa tabla:

> select
> coalesce(nullif(s[1], ''), 'public') as grantee,
> s[2] as privileges
> from
> pg_class c
> join pg_namespace n on n.oid = relnamespace
> join pg_roles r on r.oid = relowner,
> unnest(coalesce(relacl::text[], format('{%s=arwdDxt/%s}', rolname, rolname)::text[])) acl,
> regexp_split_to_array(acl, '=|/') s
> where relname = 'VISTA_MATERIALIZADA';

EN pg_class me aparece la vista materializada...

```
"postgres"  "arwdDxt"
"public"    "arwdDxt"
```

Pero en information_schema.table_privileges no aparece ..

¿Como podría hacer para que el `REFRESH MATERIALIALIZED VIEW` lo pueda realizar el trigger siendo cualquier usuario de la BD? Porque solo funciona si es postgres o SUPER.

Como creo un nuevo rol con permisos super, meto a todos los usuarios, y asigno ese rol como propietario de esta tabla maerializada??

Muchísimas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrás utilizar la opción `SECURITY DEFINER` para el trigger, esto le da permiso de ejecutar las cosas dentro del trigger como si fuera el dueño del trigger y si es `postgres` ese usuario tendria sus "beneficios", y por favor pon código del trigger, si es posible, para ver algunos otros detalles que podamos ayudarte, pues estamos un poco a ciegas con eso

Comment: create or replace function pro.refresh_mat_view()
returns trigger language plpgsql
as $$
begin
   REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW CONCURRENTLY pro.responsable_presu__vista;      
   return null;
end $$;


en pocas palabras... si añado el SECURITY DEFINER... en al funcion...se arregla el problema??? Ya estaba yo creando roles y viendo como asignarlos a todos los usuarios :(

Answer (score 0):

Efectivamente poniendo ese "SECURITY DEFINER" se arregla todo el problema...y no tengo que alterar los permisos ni roles de los usuarios... Que merluzo estoy.

Mil gracias :D